Drag and drop images in org file. NON admin account, windows 10, emacs in user directory
I am new to emacs.
Emacs setup: windows 10, no admin rights, emacs unpacked in user directory and works fine for simple org documents - compiling using pandoc and references work fine with org cite.
I tried using org-download drag and drop but it does not work.  I have in my init file.
   (use-package org-download
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;;add support to dired
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'org-download-enable)
  (setq-default org-download-heading-1v1 nil)
   (setq org-download-method 'directory)
      (setq org-download-image-dir (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) "-img"))
      (setq org-download-image-org-width 600)
      (setq org-download-link-format "[[file:%s]]\n"
        org-download-abbreviate-filename-function #'file-relative-name)
      (setq org-download-link-format-function #'org-download-link-format-function-default))

(require 'org-download)

So I get option for M-org-download-yank but nothing happens. similar for other org-download options.
I next tried to use a custom function as described for windows but I guess it works on emacs in wsl2 not like I have installed it by unpacking emacs in my user directory.
    (defun my-org-paste-image ()
      "Paste an image into a time stamped unique-named file in the
    same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
      (interactive)
      (let* ((target-file
              (concat
               (make-temp-name
                (concat (buffer-file-name)
                        "_"
                        (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"))) ".png"))
             (wsl-path
              (concat (as-windows-path(file-name-directory target-file))
                      "\\"
                      (file-name-nondirectory target-file)))
             (ps-script
              (concat "(Get-Clipboard -Format image).Save('" wsl-path "')")))
    
        (powershell ps-script)
    
        (if (file-exists-p target-file)
            (progn (insert (concat "[[" target-file "]]"))
                   (org-display-inline-images))
          (user-error
           "Error pasting the image, make sure you have an image in the clipboard!"))
        ))
    
    (defun as-windows-path (unix-path)
      "Takes a unix path and returns a matching WSL path
    (e.g. \\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\tmp)"
      ;; substring removes the trailing \n
      (substring
       (shell-command-to-string
        (concat "wslpath -w " unix-path)) 0 -1))
    
    (defun powershell (script)
      "executes the given script within a powershell and returns its return value"
      (call-process "powershell.exe" nil nil nil
                    "-Command" (concat "& {" script "}")))

